# Gson deserialization issue

Tags: java, gson

When I tried to deserialize this json:

```
{
    "Token": "",
    "Error": "Invalid Username or Password",
    "Location": null
}
```

I got an error:

```
10-06 14:51:26.310: DEBUG/LoginActivity(18676): JsonParseException: Expecting object found: "{\"Token\":\"\",\"Error\":\"Invalid Username or Password\",\"Location\":null}"
```

My code:

```
LoginResult loginResult = new Gson().fromJson(responseContent, LoginResult.class);


public class LoginResult {
     @SerializedName("Token")
     private String token;

     @SerializedName("Error")
     private String error;

         @SerializedName("Location")
     private Location location;

     public String getToken() {
        return token;
     }

     public String getError() {
        return error;
     }

     public Location getLocation() {
        return location;
     }

public class Location {
    @SerializedName("AssignmentID")
    private String assignmentID;

    @SerializedName("LocationName")
    private String locationName;

    @SerializedName("Brand")
    private String brand;

    @SerializedName("Address")
    private String address;

    @SerializedName("Information")
    private String information;
}   
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: I have tried your code, It works perfectly well without exception. Are you sure there string is what you have given us? I tried with "{\"Token\": \"\",\"Error\": \"Invalid Username or Password\",\"Location\": null}"

Answer (score 0):

I looked up your error on Google, and found the error spitting out [this text](http://groups.google.com/group/google-gson/browse_thread/thread/162c71ce5cd9dc0d?pli=1):
`[{"status":"ikas","nid":16,"name":"Mu","year": 2005,"type":"college"}]`
In that case, the error was due to the object being enclosed in an array.

Given that, it would seem as though the problem is that responseContent is full of invalid literal backslashes (the error is not just showing escaped quotation marks, as it would appear at first glance).